# Avoid using assign() in R

Tags: r, variable-assignment

In many answers here in SO, posters advise to avoid using `assign()` to create new variables inside a loop, like this code reproduced here from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31174509/using-vectors-as-inputs-in-new-variables/31174658#31174658):

```
myDf <- mtcars
splitVar <- factor(myDf$gear)
levelsVar <- levels(splitVar)
splitDataFrame <- split(myDf, splitVar)
for (i in 1:length(levelsVar)) {
  assign(paste0("newDataFrameGear", levelsVar[i]), data.frame(splitDataFrame[i]))
}
ls(pattern = "^newData")
```

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17559390/why-is-using-assign-bad) explains why it is considered bad practice, but what other options are available to prevent this?

Comment: Did you [Google](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17559390/why-is-using-assign-bad)?

Comment: The duplicate might only cover the "bad" part.  Could it be that the workaround portion of his question still be left unanswered?

Comment: I had 2 questions. The question marked as a duplicate does not show good examples of how to prevent this.

Comment: For "how to prevent this", see also [How to make a list of data frames in R?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24376207/903061).

Answer (score 1):

Why not just keep using the original list, but assign the names you want:

```
names(splitDataFrame) <- paste0("newDataFrameGear",
                                as.character(levels(splitVar)))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I was meaning a more general solution, not only for this case in specific.